# How to create a package that would copy all files from a given folder into a new folder and save the file name in the table using ssis

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis

How can I create a package to copy all Excel files from a given folder into a new folder and 
save each of the file name in the same table using ssis?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this via a For Each Loop Container, a File System Task, and a Data Flow Task.

Here's a tutorial on the For Each Loop container: [SSIS Looping Over Files](http://www.sqlis.com/sqlis/post/Looping-over-files-with-the-Foreach-Loop.aspx)
  You won't need to deal with the connection string expression, you'll just dump the mapped variable into a table.

Here's a tutorial going over the File System Task: [Copy and Rename a File in SSIS](http://www.bidn.com/blogs/KeithHyer/bidn-blog/2465/copy-and-rename-a-file-in-ssis-using-the-file-system-task)

Hard to get into much detail without re-writing a tutorial, there are many out there just a matter of piecing it together.  I'd set up the loop and data flow task first, you can use a SQL source and just select the filename to insert into your table. After that's set add in the file system task.